# Problem reading from ADS1115 from Raspberry Pi using i2c

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use an adc converter (ads1115 ).

But when I try to run the example script; simpletest.py

I get:

Reading ADS1x15 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...

### |      0 |      1 |      2 |      3 |

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "simpletest.py", line 43, in 
        values[i] = adc.read_adc(i, gain=GAIN)
      File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_ADS1x15/ADS1x15.py", line 192, in read_adc
      File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_ADS1x15/ADS1x15.py", line 133, in _read
      File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 136, in readList
      File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 216, in read_i2c_block_data
    TypeError: one character string expected

When i run the diagnostic command: i2cdetect I get this

```
i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Full code of python script (simpletest.py) showing the error message:

```
# Simple demo of reading each analog input from the ADS1x15 and printing it to
# the screen.
# Author: Tony DiCola
# License: Public Domain
import time

# Import the ADS1x15 module.
import Adafruit_ADS1x15


# Create an ADS1115 ADC (16-bit) instance.
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

# Or create an ADS1015 ADC (12-bit) instance.
#adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1015()

# Note you can change the I2C address from its default (0x48), and/or the I2C
# bus by passing in these optional parameters:
#adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1015(address=0x49, busnum=1)

# Choose a gain of 1 for reading voltages from 0 to 4.09V.
# Or pick a different gain to change the range of voltages that are read:
#  - 2/3 = +/-6.144V
#  -   1 = +/-4.096V
#  -   2 = +/-2.048V
#  -   4 = +/-1.024V
#  -   8 = +/-0.512V
#  -  16 = +/-0.256V
# See table 3 in the ADS1015/ADS1115 datasheet for more info on gain.
GAIN = 1

print('Reading ADS1x15 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')
# Print nice channel column headers.
print('| {0:>6} | {1:>6} | {2:>6} | {3:>6} |'.format(*range(4)))
print('-' * 37)
# Main loop.
while True:
    # Read all the ADC channel values in a list.
    values = [0]*4
    for i in range(4):
        # Read the specified ADC channel using the previously set gain value.
        values[i] = adc.read_adc(i, gain=GAIN)
        # Note you can also pass in an optional data_rate parameter that controls
        # the ADC conversion time (in samples/second). Each chip has a different
        # set of allowed data rate values, see datasheet Table 9 config register
        # DR bit values.
        #values[i] = adc.read_adc(i, gain=GAIN, data_rate=128)
        # Each value will be a 12 or 16 bit signed integer value depending on the
        # ADC (ADS1015 = 12-bit, ADS1115 = 16-bit).
    # Print the ADC values.
    print('| {0:>6`enter code here`} | {1:>6} | {2:>6} | {3:>6} |'.format(*values))
    # Pause for half a second.
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

please advise.

Kevin

Comment: It's very hard to suggest what's wrong with a program we can't see.

Comment: For anybody else having this issue, I finally got round it by switching to 'circuit python' which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with python2.7 then I install Adafruit ADS1115 library using `pip3 install Adafruit-ADS1x15` and after that I run my script using python3 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

uffff long search. No issues using python 3, but my ROS is installed with Python 2.7, so I need to resolve the issue. This is how I did following a Chinese forum:

Raspberry pi:

1. mkdir ~/temp
2. cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
3. cp -p Adafruit_PureIO-1.1.5-py2.7.egg  ~/temp
4. cd ~/temp
5. unzip *.egg
6. cd Adafruit_PureIO
7. edit the file smbus.py
   line 255
   change: cmdstring[i] = val
   by
   cmdstring[i] = str(val)
   save the file
8. cd ..
9. zip -r Adafruit_PureIO-1.1.5-py2.7.egg Adafruit_PureIO-1.1.5-py2.7.egg /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

I wrote this steps after I find the solution.

Now you can run the example and your own code

### pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15/examples $ python simpletest.py
Reading ADS1x15 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...
|      0 |      1 |      2 |      3 |

|   1157 |    845 |    292 |    292 |
|   1157 |    845 |    296 |    294 |
|   1157 |    845 |    293 |    296 |

Juan.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem as you.

It seems that it happened because your raspberry pi uses the default python2.

Try to install python3 on your raspberry pi.

```
pip install python3
```

then change the python3 as the default one. What i did was deleting the link of python2, and setting up a new link of python3.

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
```

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python
```

please code `python`to find out which one is used in your raspberry. If python3 is shown, then you will successfully read the ADS1115.

That is what I ddi to solve this problem. I wish it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that inapt wiring can cause the I2C address to change during operation, so that the device is no more accessible at the original address.

I wrote a sample program to try several configurations for ADS1115 without using 
AdaFruit library, which seems to have helped some people:
http://smartypies.com/projects/ads1115-with-raspberrypi-and-python/ads1115runner